# Perforce workspace create issue

Tags: perforce, workspace

While creating workspace in perforce, I got below error

You should define workspace view in more detail. (minimum 2 depth)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard Perforce error, and is therefore most likely coming from a custom trigger set up by your Perforce admin.  In order to resolve a custom trigger failure you will need to consult with your Perforce administrator (i.e. the person who defined the trigger) to determine what conditions are required to satisfy the trigger.

If you would like to learn more about how to define triggers, see https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/chapter.scripting.html
(this is not useful to you as an end user encountering a trigger failure, but may provide additional context on how triggers work from your admin's perspective).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22892273)

Comment: Added a little more verbiage, but "this is coming from a trigger" is really the only valid answer to this type of Perforce usage question.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround/fix i got is,
make sure to select a folder in "Workspace root" , which has last two level of empty folders, 
for example, 
Suppose you choose "C:\Users\stackuser\workspace\project\codes", then make sure, "project and codes are two empty folders